# How to decrease image size(height, width) without losing its resolution and quality

Tags: image, imagick

I want to decrease height and width of a image without losing its resolution, so afterwards if i want to make image height and width as original, it looks same.

I dont know how this can be achieved. Will just changing image's height and width and later increasing will result in loss of resolution to image?

Comment: "not loosing resolution" means as much as "keeping width*height pixel size", which is a paradox when you say if you want to decrease width and height. do you mean you want to temporarily cache a smaller image for display, but keep the original image?

Comment: actually what i need is to display a smaller image, where user selects  area to crop and then i need to crop same area from the larger image.

Answer (score 0):

Got to the Image > Image Size > Resample Image and select Bicubic Sharper from the dropdown menu and you can get the output